# Any way to test asynchronous jquery plugin with qunit that avoids embedded "start()" and keeps it asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, asynchronous, qunit

I'm writing my first jquery plugin. It relies heavily on ajax calls to a server. Ordinarily, the ajax calls in the plugin will run, as is standard, asynchronously.

I'm using qunit for testing. My first attempt failed in the classic way:

```
test ('check asynchronous call', function ()
{
    stop();
    $.my_plugin('do asynchronous call');
    start();
    equal('expected val', var_set_after_async_call_finishes, 
      'async var set as expected?');
})
```

Namely, the "equal" ran before the asynchronous call finished.

It seems that I can modify the plugin code in two ways:

1. embed "start()" in the plugin directly (but this clutters it up with code that shouldn't run in production)
2. add an optional argument to my_plugin that forces the $.ajax to run synchronously.

I've taken the second approach, adding an optional argument to my_plugin that, when set to false, runs the ajax function synchronously. Then I modified the test to read:

```
test ('check asynchronous call', function ()
{
    async = false;
    $.my_plugin('do asynchronous call', async);
    equal('expected val', var_set_after_async_call_finishes, 
      'async var set as expected?');
})
```

This works.

But is there a way to test the plugin reliably without modifying its code in any way?

Comment: Yes, try using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like mocking $.ajax so that it returns the data you want and it runs in sync. Then you can write different cases for different returns from the server.

```
 (function ($) {

    var originalAjax;
    var mockData = { whatever: "server returns" };

    module("Testing plugin with mock ajax", {
        setup: function () {
            var mockAjax = function (options) {
                start();
                options.success(mockData);
            };

            originalAjax = $.ajax;
            $.ajax = mockAjax;

        },
        teardown: function () {
            $.ajax = originalAjax;
        }
    });

    test("Your test", function () {
        stop();

        $.my_plugin('do asynchronous call');

        ok(true, "your assertion, whatever your plugin changes or returns");

    });

})(jQuery);
```